# R: Extract Numeric Value (with decimal) from String

Tags: r, extract

I have a column with a string value:

```
"geo:lat:55.892994,lng:10.510947,address:content:NA"
```

And I want to have twonew columnn with:

```
column1: 55.892994       
column2: 10.510947
```

Would you help me with R code?

I was trying to use `str_extract` and `str_split`, but I cannot seem to achieve the result

Comment: What exactly did you try, and what about it didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

```r
string <- "geo:lat:55.892994,lng:10.510947,address:content:NA"
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(string=string) %>%
  extract(string, c("lat", "lng"), "lat:([0-9.]+),lng:([0-9.]+)",convert = TRUE)
#>        lat      lng
#> 1 55.89299 10.51095
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

string <- "geo:lat:55.892994,lng:10.510947,address:content:NA"

data.frame(string=string) %>% 
transmute(column1=str_remove_all(str_extract_all(string, '.*\\d+(?=\\d\\,lng)'),'[a-zA-Z:]'),
          column2=str_remove_all(str_extract_all(string, '(?<=\\,).*\\d+(?=\\d\\,address)'),'[a-zA-Z:]') 
                                                                  )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
   column1  column2
1 55.89299 10.51094
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub` from base R.

```
data <- data.frame(xy="geo:lat:55.892994,lng:10.510947,address:content:NA")

data$lat <- sub('.*lat:(\\d+\\.\\d+).*', '\\1', data$xy)
data$lng <- sub('.*lng:(\\d+\\.\\d+).*', '\\1', data$xy)
```

See `help(regex)` for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex.

```
library(stringr)
s="geo:lat:55.892994,lng:10.510947,address:content:NA"
str_match(s,"lat:([0-9]{2}.[0-9]{6}).*?lng:([0-9]{2}.[0-9]{6})")
```

Outputs

```
     [,1]                          [,2]        [,3]       
[1,] "lat:55.892994,lng:10.510947" "55.892994" "10.510947"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gregexpr` with `[0-9.]+` to find the numbers and `regmatches` to extract them.

```
cbind(x, do.call(rbind, regmatches(x$s, gregexpr("[0-9.]+", x$s))))
#                                                   s         1         2
#1 geo:lat:55.892994,lng:10.510947,address:content:NA 55.892994 10.510947
#2 geo:lat:57.892994,lng:14.510947,address:content:NA 57.892994 14.510947
```

Data

```
x <- data.frame(s = c("geo:lat:55.892994,lng:10.510947,address:content:NA",
                      "geo:lat:57.892994,lng:14.510947,address:content:NA"))
```